# How To Reuse Activity on Top of Stack

Tags: android

My app has a single entry activity called "Main". In "Main" I call one of three
   other activities A, B, or C (based on a preference) and then immediately exit/finish 
   "Main" so that only A, B, or C are active.

I also have a permanent notification in the notification bar 
   that users can pull down (at any time) to conveniently restart my App (calls intent 
   with "Main" component).

The problem is that if my app is already running and users pull down the notification
   and restart, I get A or B or C running on top of the previous activity (also A, or
   B, or C). How can I avoid this (i.e. reuse the activity on top of the stack)?

I've tried Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_* and nothing seems to work. I've tried launchModes
   in the Manifest and it also didn't seem to work. Any ideas? Any help appreciated....jh

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to do this that does what I want (though I'm still testing it)...

In the Android Manifest, for activities A, B, and C, I added the following line:

android:launchMode="singleTask"

This had the result of reusing activities A, B, or C if they were already at the
top of the stack so that they wouldn't be restarted on top of themselves (which 
was requiring hitting the BACK button twice to exit the task).

Comment: I found this useful when launching an Activity from a notification, where the stack would end up with two or more (one per notification) instances of the same Activity. In combination with onNewIntent it's possible to update the existing Activity with new content (via Intent extras.)