# How can i programmatically show activity on the top of task stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

My application start foreground service witch keep connection to server. It's show notification with pendingIntent witch show MainActivity. When i (user) tap on application icon  (on desktop or application list) it's show "task stack". I mean if was lunched MainActivity it shows it, if user go to activity B or C (or lunch some other activities) it shows it (i mean top activity from task stack). There is a problem - if user tap on notification he see again MainActivity (on the top of the stack) but i expect top of tack stack (activity B,C or other witch was lunched by user at the end).

Half solves when i set attribute for MainActivity "singleTask", now it's always root of task stack, BUT a'm loosing all activities (B, C and other wich user lunched). Solution like in [Reuse Activity on Top of Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057031/how-to-reuse-activity-on-top-of-stack) simular, but i need only one activity at root.

Maybe my logic is wrong and i need some another way to resolve this problem. But i want to know how can i programmaticly show task stack (top activity) like application icon does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) describes how to handle navigation correctly.

In short, if users tap on your navigation and you take them to an Activity in your app, when they click Back they should up in your app's Activity hierarchy until they reach the Home screen. They should *never* go to the stack in another task. That is, if they're in your app in Activity C, and you send a notification which they click that takes them to Activity A, then clicking Back should take them to the *parent of A*, and not to C. If they want to go to C, they can use Recents.

On older platforms, Recents isn't available.

This is by design.

To construct the proper synthetic back stack, use [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I readed again "Tasks and Back Stack" very carefully and find solution - problem was that MainActivity was not action launcher and main (in Manifest file, only in pendingIntent), that's why it was created by he system instead of resume all task stack (with last seend activity) when notification hits.